# Docker kill command not working: Cannot kill container

Tags: docker

I am trying to kill (force stop) a MySQL DB container and it is refusing to die:

```
$ docker kill 55718df7a9d6
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: 55718df7a9d6: Container 55718df7a9d6600501bbd248fe0c1ef7da3f970fea84461cbe5f10c70f0cbe22 is not running
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
55718df7a9d6        mysql:8             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago       Restarting (1) 58 seconds ago                       my-main-db
```

When I try to kill it:

```
$ docker stop 55718df7a9d6
55718df7a9d6
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
55718df7a9d6        mysql:8             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 minutes ago      Restarting (1) 17 minutes ago                       my-main-db
```

**How can I force this to die and clean up so that `docker ps` returns no results?**

Comment: You can use `docker stop 55718df7a9d6` to remove it since it's not running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--force` or `-f` shorthand to force-remove a container.

`docker rm -f <your-container-name or id>`

Comment: This just leads to "Could not kill running container <ID>, cannot remove - tried to kill container, but did not receive an exit event"

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use the `docker stop <id>` command, since your container is restarting, if you try to kill it while it’s not running, you’ll get the error above

**Updating the answer based on your new edit**

You can forcefully delete your container by issuing the `docker rm <container_id> -f` and then recreate it

Comment: Thanks @EdwardKirk (+1), I should have mentioned that I tried that before. Please see my edits. How can I make it so that `docker ps` shows no results?

Comment: If it’s stuck in a restarting loop, you can try to forcefully delete `docker rm 55718df7a9d6 -f` and then recreate it